# how to create “fill in the blank” questions using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to the technologies and learning angular js by developing a quiz app using **angularJS**. I want to mix the questions of **Multiple choice questions** and **fill in the blank questions**. I have created multiple choice questions but I am not able to create fill in the blank questions. could someone please give some suggestions, how to create fill in the blank questions.

**for example:** how ---you?, what --- you doing?. these kinds of questions.

here is my code:

**questions.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="questionsController" ng-init="StartTimer()">
            <div id="test_status" style="text-align:left">
                <h3 ng-show='ques'>Question {{pos+1}} of {{questions.length}}</h3>
                <h3 ng-hide='ques'>Test Completed  </h3>
            </div>
            <ol style="list-style-type:none">
                <li id="test" colspan="3">
                    <div ng-show="ques">
                        <h3>{{question}}</h3>
                        <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>{{chA}}
                        <br>
                        <input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'>{{chB}}
                        <br>
                        <input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'>{{chC}}
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <button ng-click='checkAnswer()'>Next</button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <div ng-hide='ques'>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <div class="panel panel-danger">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Score Card</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                    <h3>You have got {{correct}} correct of {{questions.length}} questions</h3>
                                    <h4>Exam Finished in Time :{{minuteleft}} Minutes {{sec}} Seconds</h4>
                                    <div ng-controller="resultController">
                                        <button ng-click='click()' class="btn btn-success">Continue</button>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Time Limit</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h2>{{min}}:{{sec}}</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </body>
```

and **main.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
myApp.controller('questionsController', function($scope,$interval,$filter,$http) {

    $scope.pos = 0, $scope.correct = 0, $scope.ques = true;

    $scope.questions = [
        ["Which of the following a is not a keyword in Java ?", "class", "interface", "extends", "C"],

        ["Which of the following is an interface ?", "Thread", "Date", "Calender", "A"],

        ["Which company released Java Version 8 ?", "Sun", "Oracle", "Adobe", "A"],

        ["What is the length of Java datatype int ?", "32 bit", "16 bit", "None", "C"],

        ["What is the default value of Java datatype boolean?", "true", "false", "0", "A"]
    ];


    $scope.totalsecoriginal = $scope.totalsec = 60;
    $scope.totalsec--;
    $scope.min = parseInt($scope.totalsec / 60, 10);
    $scope.sec = $scope.totalsec - ($scope.min * 60);
    $scope.date = new Date();
    $scope.hhmmss = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'hh:mm:ss a');

    $scope.currentTime = new Date();
    $scope.currentTime.setSeconds($scope.currentTime.getSeconds() + 60);


    function _(x) {
        console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById(x)));
        return angular.element(document.getElementById(x))[0];
    }
    $scope.interval = $interval(function() {
        if ($scope.sec === 0) {
            $scope.min--;
            $scope.sec = 60;
        }
        $scope.sec--;
    }, 1000);
    $scope.$watch('sec', function() {
        if ($scope.min === 0 && $scope.sec === 0) {
            $interval.cancel($scope.interval);
            window.alert('Time Up!!!');
            $scope.pos = $scope.questions.length;
            $scope.temp = true;
            $scope.renderQuestion();
        }

    })
    $scope.renderQuestion = function() {
        if ($scope.pos >= $scope.questions.length) {
            $scope.ques = false;
            if (!$scope.temp) { $scope.temp = false;
                $interval.cancel($scope.interval);
            }
            $scope.showscore = Math.round($scope.correct / $scope.questions.length * 100);
            $scope.minuteleft = parseInt(($scope.totalsecoriginal - $scope.totalsec) / 60, 10);

            $scope.pos = 0;
            return false;
        }
        $scope.question = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][0];
        $scope.chA = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][1];
        $scope.chB = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][2];
        $scope.chC = $scope.questions[$scope.pos][3];
    }

    $scope.checkAnswer = function() {
        $scope.choices = angular.element(document.getElementsByName('choices'));
        $scope.choice = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.choices.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.choices[i].checked) {
                $scope.choice = $scope.choices[i].value;
                $scope.choices[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
        if ($scope.choice == $scope.questions[$scope.pos][4]) {
            $scope.correct++;
        }
        $scope.pos++;
        $scope.renderQuestion();

    };
    $scope.renderQuestion();

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply use an input box for fill in the blank <input type="text" id="blank1" name="blank1"> and use css to have only bottom border

input {
  outline: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 2px;
  border-color: blue
}
input:focus {
  border-color: green
}